# Good book or online resources for systems of linear ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation, online-resources

I am looking for a good and comprehensive book or online resource on systems of linear ordinary differential equations. It has to describe well the solution, stability and determination of arbitrary constants of n x n systems in normal form, including a lot of nonhomogenous cases.

Most of the resources I seem to find are about 2 x 2 or 3 x 3 system and no generalisations to the nth dimension are made.

Comment: If you google "ODE + pdf" you will very likely find lecture notes on several university servers around the globe. Lectures are a good and cheap source for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking specifically about linear systems, check out this book: ["Linear Ordinary Differential Equations" by Coddington and Carlson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8120346858).

Comment: @Moo Thanks, I fixed it.